# Why is ViewPager doesn't running class?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an activity that has a ViewPager, as following:

```
public class timetables extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;

private RelativeLayout page1;
private RelativeLayout page2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timetables);
    Intent intentTimetables = getIntent();
    setTitle(Global.lineName);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MainPageAdapter());
}

 class MainPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        View page;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                if (page1 == null) {
                    page1 = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(timetables.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_timetable_1, collection, false);
                }
                page = page1;
                break;
((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);

        return page;
    }
}
```

And when I run it, it loads good `activity_timetable_1`, but it doesn't run the code I have in that class, for example:

```
public class timetable_1 extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timetable_1);

    GridView gridWorking = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridWorking);
    gridWorking.setAdapter(new textAdapter(this));

}
}
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much

Comment: I ran your code. On my side it is displaying labels. The only thing, that I don't like is this line: android:layout_below="@+id/textView15", as this textview is not defined in layout

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the discomfort. I have just updated the question because what is wrong isn't the Gridview, but the ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (page1 == null) {
                page1 = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.activity_timetable_1, collection, false);
            }
```

Do you expect when this inflates the custom view you have will be called?

Replace it with:

```
  if (page1 == null) {
                page1 = new Activity1Form(this);
            }
```

Activity1Form = timetable_1

Also, extends ViewGroup instead of FragmentActivity at timetable_1, with this you should modify the class, remove the onCreate and place the code inside it on the constructor.

```
public class Activity1Form extends ViewGroup {

public Activity1Form(Context ctx) {
    LayoutInflater.from(timetables.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_timetable_1, collection, true);

    GridView gridWorking = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridWorking);
    gridWorking.setAdapter(new textAdapter(this));

}
}
```

You should instantiate your class instead of the layout.

EDIT:

Also, your activity_1 (awful name by the way), is a Activity and cant be placed inside another Activity or used as a Fragment, you must extende Fragment or View (or any View child such RelativeLayout/ViewGroup)

Comment: I'm sorry but I am new on Java, could you please tell me what do I have to do? Thank you.

Comment: But in a new file? Because if I put this: public class Activity1Form extends ViewGroup {

                public Activity1Form(Context ctx) {
                    LayoutInflater.from(timetables.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_timetable_1, collection, true);

                    GridView gridWorking = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridWorking);
                    gridWorking.setAdapter(new textAdapter(this));

                }
            }

            switch (position) {                                                                                        I have many errors

Comment: Well, fix them.. just a typo, LayoutInflater.from(ctx) instead of timetables.this, another error can be the name of your class that should match the one of the file. Other ones you will need to handle